# GDI printer Device Context in a Worker Thread randomly fails

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++builder, gdi

I managed to create a GDI-based bitmap-file printer routine. It works stable and without any leaks. The only drawback of course is it's freezing tha UI during the spooler tranfser. The solution attampt was moving the print routine into a worker thread. Here's the code (error checking removed):

```
void __fastcall PRINT_THREAD::Execute()
{
  while(!Terminated)
  {
   Synchronize(&TalkToOwningThread);
   if(PrintFilePath!="") PrintImage(PrintFilePath);
   Sleep(10);
  }
}


void __fastcall PRINT_THREAD::PrintImage(WideString PrintFilePath)
{
  HDC     hDC;
  DOCINFO di;
  int     w,h;
  bool    success=true;
  TCHAR   szString[32]  = TEXT("Printed from a thread");
  WideString PrinterName="FinePrint";

  TBitmap  *bmp = new TBitmap();
  TPicture *pic = new TPicture();

  hDC=CreateDC(TEXT("WINSPOOL"),PrinterName.c_bstr(),NULL,NULL);

  w=GetDeviceCaps(hDC, HORZRES);
  h=GetDeviceCaps(hDC, VERTRES);

  SecureZeroMemory(&di,sizeof(DOCINFO));
  di.cbSize = sizeof(DOCINFO);
  di.lpszDocName = TEXT("Print Job");

  StartDoc(hDC,&di);
  StartPage(hDC);

  try
  {
    pic->LoadFromFile(PrintFilePath);

    bmp->Width=w;  // set the bitmap dimensions to the printer dimensions
    bmp->Height=h;

    // fill the bitmap with 1:1 print content
    bmp->Canvas->StretchDraw(TRect(0,0,w-1,h-1),pic->Graphic); 
  }
  catch(...){success=false;}

  if(success)
  {
      BitBlt(hDC,0,0,w,h, bmp->Canvas->Handle,0,0, SRCCOPY);
      TextOut(hDC,0,100,szString,lstrlen(szString));
  }

  EndDoc(hDC);
  if(hDC) DeleteDC(hDC);

  delete pic;
  delete bmp;
```

}

The results:

- Each print call produces on page through the printer - OK
- Only about 2 of 10 pages contain the bitmap - Not OK
- All pages contain the test-line - OK
- Each call leaves one more GDI-ressource added (Task Manager) -
  Not OK

I already tried moving the CreateDC/DeleteDC-functions back to the main thread and tranferring the hDC down to the worker thread - Same results.

Are there any ideas to get this animal running?

Environment:
C++Builder 10.1 Berlin, Windows10, 16GB

Thank You.

Comment: Put `EndPage(hDC);` before `EndDoc(hDC);` but that's probably not the cause of the leak.

Comment: Which C++Builder? GDI is winapi based and any visual component calls should not be executed from outside the main message handling thread. Otherwise the winapi goes haywire causing random bugs/glitches/error/crashes anywhere in the app even on unrelated winapi calls. Hence missing rendered stuff, leaks etc ... Not sure if that is still the case in Win10 but in all previous versions is this a problem so I doubt they fixed it...

Comment: @Spektre plain GDI works fine in worker threads. It is the VCL's UI framework that is not safe outside of the main UI thread, due to how it uses global resources that are not protected from concurrent access, how it uses HWNDs that are thread-bound, etc, not because of GDI. I will point out, however, that when using `TBitmap` in a worker thread, you MUST `(un)lock` its `Canvas` while working with it or else the main UI thread can rip out GDI resources behind the `TBitmap`'s back, due to the way the `Graphics` unit caches and cleans up GDI resources that may be shared by multiple objects.

Comment: @RemyLebeau good to know.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comments!

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani you are right, I have added the EndPage(hDC) to get it into good style. Unfortunetely there was no change regarding to the errors.

Comment: @Spektre I agree with your warnings about addressing the VCL UI from outside threads. I was assuming that a GDI operation with a printer driver would not thouch the main thread.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau your point about locking the Canvas seems to be very promising. I will try it just now and come back soon.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau it works. You saved not only my day, you definitely saved an interesting new project. My honest respect for your deep knowledge. Thank you! Reiner

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Remy, I added the Lock/Unlock-pair:

```
TBitmap  *bmp = new TBitmap();
TPicture *pic = new TPicture();

bmp->Canvas->Lock();

----
----

EndPage(hDC);
EndDoc(hDC);

bmp->Canvas->Unlock();

if(hDC) DeleteDC(hDC);
delete pic;
delete bmp;
```

Finally the animal runs like a charm - no more missing graphics and no more GDI leaks.